Is it possible to PUT/PATCH a json file located in the public folder of a vite+react project?
I am trying to use a json file from the public folder as a mock db, I am able to fetch the json file using the get method but unable to update it. Here's the working get method:
axios.get('./userData.json')
     .then((response) => {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
              throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
          }
          return response.data;
          })
      .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
      })

I tried using put, post and patch and had no success. I probably shouldn't use node as I was asked to "save the new user data to a JSON file that will be in assets folder".

Sounds like you need a backend service.

To my knowledge, this is not possible only via using axios in client side. The public folder in a Vite project is meant for static assets that are served directly without any processing by the build tool. Public folders are copied to the root of your build output directory and are not processed by Vite's build pipeline.
Alternatively, this can be achieved by both client and server-side component together.
Refer the server side code to update public folder:
    const express = require('express');
    const fs = require('fs').promises;
    const app = express();
    const PORT = 3000;
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    
    app.put('/updateUserData', async (req, res) => { // Controller Endpoint to handle PUT request to update userData.json
      try {
        
        let userData = await fs.readFile('./public/userData.json', 'utf-8'); // Read existing JSON file
        userData = JSON.parse(userData);        
        
        userData = { ...userData, ...req.body }; // Update data Assuming req.body contains the updated user data
    
        
        await fs.writeFile('./public/userData.json', JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2)); // Write updated data back to JSON file
    
        res.status(200).send('User data updated successfully');
       } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
      }
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });

Its respective client-side goes as follows :
import axios from 'axios';


const updateUser = async (newUserData) => { // Function to update user data
  try {
    await axios.put('/updateUserData', newUserData);
    console.log('User data updated successfully');
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating user data:', error);
  }
};

